# C++20 concepts using ADL with circular dependency

Tags: c++, c++20, circular-dependency, c++-concepts, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm having a problem with concepts using ADL.

edit 1: I mention ADL since the `parse` functions are supposed to be overloaded with user defined types.

The `from_string_view_parsable` concept doesn't see the `parse` functions below since ADL doesn't apply to them.

The functions would need to be defined or forward declared before the concept's definition, however with the 2nd overload there is a circular dependency so it cannot be done.

https://godbolt.org/z/frn1jKv5E

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
concept from_string_view_parsable = requires(std::string_view sv, T& x) {
    { parse(sv, x) };
};

void parse(std::string_view input, int& out)
{
    auto ss = std::stringstream{};
    ss << input;
    ss >> out;
}

template <from_string_view_parsable T>
    requires std::default_initializable<T>
void parse(std::string_view input, std::optional<T>& out)
{
    out = T{};
    parse(input, *out);
}

template <from_string_view_parsable T>
void use_parse(T& t) {
    parse("123", t);
}

int main() {
    std::optional<int> x;
    use_parse(x);
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do fundamentally wrong or perhaps is there any workaround that would allow me to do it?

Comment: "*The from_string_view_parsable concept doesn't see the parse functions below since ADL doesn't apply to them.*" Why do you think that ADL has anything to do with it?

Comment: The code is designed to work with ADL. Sorry I didn't mention that, I want to provide overloads for primitive types and for a couple of std components but I would like for users to be able to provide overloads for their own types.

Comment: You've misunderstood. None of the functions are found via ADL. So why do you think ADL is in any way involved in the problem in question? Does the problem go away if you use a specific namespace, like `::parse`?

Comment: I've already acknowledged that ADL doesn't apply to the parse functions and I need a workaround since I forward declare is also not an option. Not sure what you are up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer the `requires` expression to a type trait, which can be forward-declared:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_from_string_view_parsable;

template <typename T>
concept from_string_view_parsable = is_from_string_view_parsable<T>::value;

void parse(std::string_view input, int& out)
{
    auto ss = std::stringstream{};
    ss << input;
    ss >> out;
}

template <from_string_view_parsable T>
    requires std::default_initializable<T>
void parse(std::string_view input, std::optional<T>& out)
{
    out = T{};
    parse(input, *out);
}

template <from_string_view_parsable T>
void use_parse(T& t) {
    parse("123", t);
}

template <typename T>
struct is_from_string_view_parsable : std::bool_constant<
    requires(std::string_view sv, T& x) {
        { parse(sv, x) };
    }
> {};

int main() {
    std::optional<int> x;
    use_parse(x);
}
```

Now, I don't know for sure that this doesn't break any rules, but I don't think it should. Be careful that the evaluation of the constraint does not change at different points in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Since concept cannot be forward declared, the definition of `from_string_view_parsable` must appear *after* the `std::optional` overload.

Instead, you can use the *requires clause* (or `static_assert`) to constrain `parse(intput, *out)` must be well-formed, something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <optional>

void parse(std::string_view input, int& out)
{
    auto ss = std::stringstream{};
    ss << input;
    ss >> out;
}

template <std::default_initializable T>
void parse(std::string_view input, std::optional<T>& out)
  requires requires { parse(input, *out); }
{
    out = T{};
    parse(input, *out);
}

template <typename T>
concept from_string_view_parsable = requires(std::string_view sv, T& x) {
    { parse(sv, x) };
};

template <from_string_view_parsable T>
void use_parse(T& t) {
    parse("123", t);
}

int main() {
    std::optional<int> x;
    use_parse(x);
}
```